# MediaElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan returns wrong value

Tags: c#, wpf

In xaml I have simple MediaElement mediaElement control with video.mp4 source.
Video duration is about 4,3 seconds.

When mediaElement.MediaOpened is fired, I am trying to get video duration.

```cs
private void mediaElement_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    double TotalTime = mediaElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds;         
    Console.WriteLine("Total video time: {0}", TotalTime);            
}
```

Console returns "Total video time: 4000".
How do I get exact video duration?

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same problem in my project and was unable to find a WPF, built-in way to get an accurate millisecond count. So, we have to go to external libraries.

I chose to go with [Javi.MediaInfo](https://github.com/jacovis/Javi.MediaInfo) for a few reasons, some of which were that it was an MIT-licensed wrapper for [MediaInfoLib](https://github.com/MediaArea/MediaInfoLib) (BSD 2-clause). Some of the other wrappers on Nuget look like they are MIT/similar licensed, but if you look at the source, they are using GPL code, as is the case with [MP-MediaInfo](https://github.com/yartat/MP-MediaInfo). To use `Javi.MediaInfo`, I had to also install [MediaInfo.Native](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MediaInfo.Native/) v19.4.0 (native `MediaInfo.dll`) from NuGet.

I ran into an issue with `Javi.MediaInfo` when trying to use the `Options` functionality. Turns out that the `MediaInfoWrapper` class uses old function declarations that don't match the latest `MediaInfo.dll`. To fix this, I made some adjustments to `MediaInfo.cs` and `MediaInfoWrapper.cs` (see below). The latter I obtained using the [19.4.0 DLL code download](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download/Windows). I also placed the entire `Javi.MediaInfo` source code in my source code to avoid issues with the former targeting `.NET Standard 2` and my project not doing so (it gave me duplicate DLL reference warnings if I used the NuGet).

**MediaInfoWrapper.cs**

```
/*  Copyright (c) MediaArea.net SARL. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 *  Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can
 *  be found in the License.html file in the root of the source tree.
 */

//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
//
// Microsoft Visual C# wrapper for MediaInfo Library
// See MediaInfo.h for help
//
// To make it working, you must put MediaInfo.Dll
// in the executable folder
//
//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

// from https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download/Windows -- for version 19.4.0; modified slightly
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

#pragma warning disable 1591 // Disable XML documentation warnings

namespace MediaInfoLib
{
    public enum StreamKind
    {
        General,
        Video,
        Audio,
        Text,
        Other,
        Image,
        Menu,
    }

    public enum InfoKind
    {
        Name,
        Text,
        Measure,
        Options,
        NameText,
        MeasureText,
        Info,
        HowTo
    }

    public enum InfoOptions
    {
        ShowInInform,
        Support,
        ShowInSupported,
        TypeOfValue
    }

    public enum InfoFileOptions
    {
        FileOption_Nothing = 0x00,
        FileOption_NoRecursive = 0x01,
        FileOption_CloseAll = 0x02,
        FileOption_Max = 0x04
    };

    public enum Status
    {
        None = 0x00,
        Accepted = 0x01,
        Filled = 0x02,
        Updated = 0x04,
        Finalized = 0x08,
    }

    public class MediaInfo : IDisposable
    {
        //Import of DLL functions. DO NOT USE until you know what you do (MediaInfo DLL do NOT use CoTaskMemAlloc to allocate memory)
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfo_New();
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern void MediaInfo_Delete(IntPtr Handle);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfo_Open(IntPtr Handle, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string FileName);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfoA_Open(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr FileName);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfo_Open_Buffer_Init(IntPtr Handle, Int64 File_Size, Int64 File_Offset);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfoA_Open(IntPtr Handle, Int64 File_Size, Int64 File_Offset);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfo_Open_Buffer_Continue(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr Buffer, IntPtr Buffer_Size);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfoA_Open_Buffer_Continue(IntPtr Handle, Int64 File_Size, byte[] Buffer, IntPtr Buffer_Size);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern Int64 MediaInfo_Open_Buffer_Continue_GoTo_Get(IntPtr Handle);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern Int64 MediaInfoA_Open_Buffer_Continue_GoTo_Get(IntPtr Handle);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfo_Open_Buffer_Finalize(IntPtr Handle);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfoA_Open_Buffer_Finalize(IntPtr Handle);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern void MediaInfo_Close(IntPtr Handle);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfo_Inform(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr Reserved);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfoA_Inform(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr Reserved);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfo_GetI(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr StreamKind, IntPtr StreamNumber, IntPtr Parameter, IntPtr KindOfInfo);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfoA_GetI(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr StreamKind, IntPtr StreamNumber, IntPtr Parameter, IntPtr KindOfInfo);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfo_Get(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr StreamKind, IntPtr StreamNumber, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string Parameter, IntPtr KindOfInfo, IntPtr KindOfSearch);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfoA_Get(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr StreamKind, IntPtr StreamNumber, IntPtr Parameter, IntPtr KindOfInfo, IntPtr KindOfSearch);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfo_Option(IntPtr Handle, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string Option, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string Value);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfoA_Option(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr Option, IntPtr Value);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfo_State_Get(IntPtr Handle);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfo_Count_Get(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr StreamKind, IntPtr StreamNumber);


        public string[] InfoParametersCSV { get; }
        //MediaInfo class
        public MediaInfo()
        {
            try
            {
                Handle = MediaInfo_New();
                this.InfoParametersCSV = this.Option("Info_Parameters_CSV").Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            }
            catch
            {
                Handle = (IntPtr)0;
            }
            if (Environment.OSVersion.ToString().IndexOf("Windows") == -1)
                MustUseAnsi = true;
            else
                MustUseAnsi = false;
        }
        ~MediaInfo() { if (Handle == (IntPtr)0) return; MediaInfo_Delete(Handle); }
        public int Open(String FileName)
        {
            if (Handle == (IntPtr)0)
                return 0;
            if (MustUseAnsi)
            {
                IntPtr FileName_Ptr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(FileName);
                int ToReturn = (int)MediaInfoA_Open(Handle, FileName_Ptr);
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(FileName_Ptr);
                return ToReturn;
            }
            else
                return (int)MediaInfo_Open(Handle, FileName);
        }
        public int Open_Buffer_Init(Int64 File_Size, Int64 File_Offset)
        {
            if (Handle == (IntPtr)0) return 0; return (int)MediaInfo_Open_Buffer_Init(Handle, File_Size, File_Offset);
        }
        public int Open_Buffer_Continue(IntPtr Buffer, IntPtr Buffer_Size)
        {
            if (Handle == (IntPtr)0) return 0; return (int)MediaInfo_Open_Buffer_Continue(Handle, Buffer, Buffer_Size);
        }
        public Int64 Open_Buffer_Continue_GoTo_Get()
        {
            if (Handle == (IntPtr)0) return 0; return (Int64)MediaInfo_Open_Buffer_Continue_GoTo_Get(Handle);
        }
        public int Open_Buffer_Finalize()
        {
            if (Handle == (IntPtr)0) return 0; return (int)MediaInfo_Open_Buffer_Finalize(Handle);
        }
        public void Close() { if (Handle == (IntPtr)0) return; MediaInfo_Close(Handle); }
        public String Inform()
        {
            if (Handle == (IntPtr)0)
                return "Unable to load MediaInfo library";
            if (MustUseAnsi)
                return Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(MediaInfoA_Inform(Handle, (IntPtr)0));
            else
                return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(MediaInfo_Inform(Handle, (IntPtr)0));
        }
        public String Get(StreamKind StreamKind, int StreamNumber, String Parameter, InfoKind KindOfInfo, InfoKind KindOfSearch)
        {
            if (Handle == (IntPtr)0)
                return "Unable to load MediaInfo library";
            if (MustUseAnsi)
            {
                IntPtr Parameter_Ptr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(Parameter);
                String ToReturn = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(MediaInfoA_Get(Handle, (IntPtr)StreamKind, (IntPtr)StreamNumber, Parameter_Ptr, (IntPtr)KindOfInfo, (IntPtr)KindOfSearch));
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(Parameter_Ptr);
                return ToReturn;
            }
            else
                return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(MediaInfo_Get(Handle, (IntPtr)StreamKind, (IntPtr)StreamNumber, Parameter, (IntPtr)KindOfInfo, (IntPtr)KindOfSearch));
        }
        public String Get(StreamKind StreamKind, int StreamNumber, int Parameter, InfoKind KindOfInfo)
        {
            if (Handle == (IntPtr)0)
                return "Unable to load MediaInfo library";
            if (MustUseAnsi)
                return Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(MediaInfoA_GetI(Handle, (IntPtr)StreamKind, (IntPtr)StreamNumber, (IntPtr)Parameter, (IntPtr)KindOfInfo));
            else
                return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(MediaInfo_GetI(Handle, (IntPtr)StreamKind, (IntPtr)StreamNumber, (IntPtr)Parameter, (IntPtr)KindOfInfo));
        }
        public String Option(String Option, String Value)
        {
            if (Handle == (IntPtr)0)
                return "Unable to load MediaInfo library";
            if (MustUseAnsi)
            {
                IntPtr Option_Ptr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(Option);
                IntPtr Value_Ptr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(Value);
                String ToReturn = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(MediaInfoA_Option(Handle, Option_Ptr, Value_Ptr));
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(Option_Ptr);
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(Value_Ptr);
                return ToReturn;
            }
            else
                return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(MediaInfo_Option(Handle, Option, Value));
        }
        public int State_Get() { if (Handle == (IntPtr)0) return 0; return (int)MediaInfo_State_Get(Handle); }
        public int Count_Get(StreamKind StreamKind, int StreamNumber) { if (Handle == (IntPtr)0) return 0; return (int)MediaInfo_Count_Get(Handle, (IntPtr)StreamKind, (IntPtr)StreamNumber); }
        private IntPtr Handle;
        private bool MustUseAnsi;

        //Default values, if you know how to set default values in C#, say me
        public String Get(StreamKind StreamKind, int StreamNumber, String Parameter, InfoKind KindOfInfo) { return Get(StreamKind, StreamNumber, Parameter, KindOfInfo, InfoKind.Name); }
        public String Get(StreamKind StreamKind, int StreamNumber, String Parameter) { return Get(StreamKind, StreamNumber, Parameter, InfoKind.Text, InfoKind.Name); }
        public String Get(StreamKind StreamKind, int StreamNumber, int Parameter) { return Get(StreamKind, StreamNumber, Parameter, InfoKind.Text); }
        public String Option(String Option_) { return Option(Option_, ""); }
        public int Count_Get(StreamKind StreamKind) { return Count_Get(StreamKind, -1); }

        private bool isdisposed = false;
        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (!this.isdisposed)
            {
                // Clean-up Unmanaged
                if (Handle != (IntPtr)0)
                {
                    MediaInfo_Delete(Handle);
                    Handle = IntPtr.Zero;
                }

                this.isdisposed = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public class MediaInfoList
    {
        //Import of DLL functions. DO NOT USE until you know what you do (MediaInfo DLL do NOT use CoTaskMemAlloc to allocate memory)
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfoList_New();
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern void MediaInfoList_Delete(IntPtr Handle);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfoList_Open(IntPtr Handle, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string FileName, IntPtr Options);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern void MediaInfoList_Close(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr FilePos);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfoList_Inform(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr FilePos, IntPtr Reserved);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfoList_GetI(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr FilePos, IntPtr StreamKind, IntPtr StreamNumber, IntPtr Parameter, IntPtr KindOfInfo);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfoList_Get(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr FilePos, IntPtr StreamKind, IntPtr StreamNumber, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string Parameter, IntPtr KindOfInfo, IntPtr KindOfSearch);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfoList_Option(IntPtr Handle, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string Option, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string Value);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfoList_State_Get(IntPtr Handle);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfoList_Count_Get(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr FilePos, IntPtr StreamKind, IntPtr StreamNumber);

        //MediaInfo class
        public MediaInfoList() { Handle = MediaInfoList_New(); }
        ~MediaInfoList() { MediaInfoList_Delete(Handle); }
        public int Open(String FileName, InfoFileOptions Options) { return (int)MediaInfoList_Open(Handle, FileName, (IntPtr)Options); }
        public void Close(int FilePos) { MediaInfoList_Close(Handle, (IntPtr)FilePos); }
        public String Inform(int FilePos) { return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(MediaInfoList_Inform(Handle, (IntPtr)FilePos, (IntPtr)0)); }
        public String Get(int FilePos, StreamKind StreamKind, int StreamNumber, String Parameter, InfoKind KindOfInfo, InfoKind KindOfSearch) { return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(MediaInfoList_Get(Handle, (IntPtr)FilePos, (IntPtr)StreamKind, (IntPtr)StreamNumber, Parameter, (IntPtr)KindOfInfo, (IntPtr)KindOfSearch)); }
        public String Get(int FilePos, StreamKind StreamKind, int StreamNumber, int Parameter, InfoKind KindOfInfo) { return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(MediaInfoList_GetI(Handle, (IntPtr)FilePos, (IntPtr)StreamKind, (IntPtr)StreamNumber, (IntPtr)Parameter, (IntPtr)KindOfInfo)); }
        public String Option(String Option, String Value) { return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(MediaInfoList_Option(Handle, Option, Value)); }
        public int State_Get() { return (int)MediaInfoList_State_Get(Handle); }
        public int Count_Get(int FilePos, StreamKind StreamKind, int StreamNumber) { return (int)MediaInfoList_Count_Get(Handle, (IntPtr)FilePos, (IntPtr)StreamKind, (IntPtr)StreamNumber); }
        private IntPtr Handle;

        //Default values, if you know how to set default values in C#, say me
        public void Open(String FileName) { Open(FileName, 0); }
        public void Close() { Close(-1); }
        public String Get(int FilePos, StreamKind StreamKind, int StreamNumber, String Parameter, InfoKind KindOfInfo) { return Get(FilePos, StreamKind, StreamNumber, Parameter, KindOfInfo, InfoKind.Name); }
        public String Get(int FilePos, StreamKind StreamKind, int StreamNumber, String Parameter) { return Get(FilePos, StreamKind, StreamNumber, Parameter, InfoKind.Text, InfoKind.Name); }
        public String Get(int FilePos, StreamKind StreamKind, int StreamNumber, int Parameter) { return Get(FilePos, StreamKind, StreamNumber, Parameter, InfoKind.Text); }
        public String Option(String Option_) { return Option(Option_, ""); }
        public int Count_Get(int FilePos, StreamKind StreamKind) { return Count_Get(FilePos, StreamKind, -1); }
    }

} //NameSpace
```

SO is not letting me paste the entire `MediaInfo.cs` file here due to character limits. To make it use the new wrapper, add `using MediaInfoWrapper = MediaInfoLib.MediaInfo;` to the top `using` statements and change occurances of `new MediaInfoWrapper(someStringVar)` to `new MediaInfoWrapper()`. After that, you should be set!